# Link field to path (automatically pulling Node Id)

Tags: nodes, views, users

I have a view "Objects" containing type Object and having fields name and size. I have another view with more features of the Objects called "Details". I set the path of the "Details" view to details/%.

What I want to do is link the name field of the Object in the first View to its details in the latter. In "output this field as a link", what path should I put for it to automatically get that field's Node ID and plug it into the URL so that it goes to its corresponding set of details? Is that not possible? Do I have to link each name manually to its details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to have the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module installed.

Then, to be able to use the `[nid]` token, you'll have to add a *Node ID* field and move it *before* the *Node name* one to be output as link. The nid field you can *Exclude from display*.

In the node name field then, set custom path to `details/[nid]`.